# Use generating functions to calculate the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)(n-k+1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Use generating functions to calculate the sum  $\sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)(n-k+1)$

And Prove it by induction.

***Attempt:***

$$A(x)= \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)(n-k+1)$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)(n-k+1))x^n$$

The series of differences is :$\{(n+1),2(n),3(n-1),4(n-2)…,1,…\}$

The generating functions of this series is : $(1-x)A(x)$

The series of differences is :$\{(n+1),(n-1),(n-3),(n-5),…,2-n,…\}$

The generating functions of this series is : $(1-x)^2A(x)$

The series of differences is :$\{(n+1),-2,-2,-2,…,-2,…\}$

The generating functions of this series is : $(1-x)A^3(x)$

The series of differences is :$\{(n+1),-(n+3),0,0,…,0,…\}$

The generating functions of this series is : $(1-x)^4A(x)$

On the other hand, the generating functions $(n+1)+(-n-3)x$,

Therefore: $(1-x)^4A(x)=(n+1)+(-n-3)x$

$$A( x) =\frac{( n+1) +( -n-3) x}{( 1-x)^{4}} =(( n+1) +( -n-3) x) \cdot \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\binom{n+4-1}{4-1} x^{n}$$

$$\displaystyle \sum _{k=0}^{n}( k+1)( n-k+1) =\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }( n+1) \cdot \binom{n+4-1}{4-1} x^{n} +\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }( -n-3) \cdot \binom{n+4-1}{4-1} x^{n+1}$$

Prove in with induction :

\begin{aligned}
( n+1) \cdot \binom{n+3}{3} +( -n-3)\binom{n+2}{3} & =\frac{( n+3)( n+2)( n+1)^{2} n}{3!} +\frac{( n+2)( n+1)( n-1) n( -n-3)}{3!}\\
 & =\frac{( n+3)( n+2)( n+1)^{2} -( n+2)( n+1)( n+3) n}{6}\\
 & =\frac{( n+3)( n+2)( n+1)}{6}\\
 & =\frac{1}{6}\left( n^{3} +6n^{2} +11n+6\right)
\end{aligned}

$$\displaystyle \sum _{k=0}^{n}( k+1)( n-k+1) =\frac{1}{6}\left( n^{3} +6n^{2} +11n+6\right)$$

induction basis: $n=0$

$$\displaystyle \sum _{k=0}^{n}( 0+1)( 0-0+1) =1=\frac{1}{6}\left( 0^{3} +6\cdotp 0^{2} +11\cdotp 0+6\right)$$

For $n+1$:

\begin{aligned}
\sum _{k=0}^{n+1}( k+1)( n-k+1) & =\sum _{k=0}^{n}( k+1)( n-k+1) +( n+2)(( n+1) -( n+1) +1)\\
 & =\frac{1}{6}\left( n^{3} +6n^{2} +11n+6\right) +( n+2)\\
\end{aligned}

If anyone can enlighten me, and find my mistakes I appreciate that.

Unfortunately, I did not succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} \sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k} x^n 
&=\sum_{k \ge 0} a_k x^k \sum_{n\ge k} a_{n-k} x^{n-k} \tag1\\
&=\sum_{k \ge 0} a_k x^k \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n x^n \tag2\\
&=\left(\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n x^n\right)^2
\end{align}
Equality $(1)$ arises from interchanging the order of summation.
Equality $(2)$ arises from the change of index $n\mapsto n+k$.
Taking $a_k = k+1$ yields
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)(n-k+1) x^n
&=\left(\sum_{n \ge 0} (n+1) x^n\right)^2 \\
&=\left(\sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n+1}{1} x^n\right)^2 \\
&=\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\right)^2 \\
&=\frac{1}{(1-x)^4} \\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0} \binom{n+3}{3} x^n \\
\end{align}
So
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)(n-k+1) = \binom{n+3}{3}$$
for $n \ge 0$.

---

Alternatively, you can prove the equivalent identity
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n+2} \binom{k-1}{1}\binom{n-k+3}{1}=\binom{n+3}{3}$$
combinatorially by counting $3$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,n+3\}$ in two different ways.  The RHS is clear.  For the LHS, condition on the middle element $k$.  You then have $k-1$ choices for the smallest element and $n-k+3$ choices for the largest element.

Comment: The answer is very impressive, btw you can explain the sigma in line (1) the equation I don't get it :(, the sigma is running from n=0 to infinity? 
thanks a lot, I really appreciate that,!

Comment: Yes $\sum_{n\ge 0}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty$

Comment: Thanks, I mean if you can explain the equation in line (1) I didn't get it.

Comment: $
\sum_{n \ge 0} \sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k} x^n
=\left(\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n x^n\right)^2.
$, where it came from ? the power of 2

Comment: [Cauchy product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)

Comment: Thanks you, I know the Cauchy product but if u can explain the move to the power of 2 in a short I will appreciate that! , thank you

Comment: I added a couple of steps just now.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you are doing, but the generating function of $(k+1)(n-k+1)$ is the derivative of the generating function of $(n-k+1).$ In other words,

if $$A_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (n-k+1) x^k,$$ then

$$A^\prime_n = \sum_{i=0}^n (k+1)(n-k+1),$$ and your sum is just equal to $A_n^\prime(1).$

Now, $$A_n(x) = n \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x^k - \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(k+1)x^k.$$

The geometric series you (hopefully) know how to sum, while the second term is the derivative of a geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear if this is off-topic.  The OP specifically requires that generating functions be used.
Other responses have covered this constraint, so I'll show an alternative approach.

Known (or routinely proven by induction) that

- $\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^n i = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)(n+1)(n).$
- $\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^n i^2 = \left(\frac{1}{6}\right) (n+1)(2n+1)(n).$

Since $(n - k + 1) = (n + 2) - (k + 1)$ 
$\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^n (k+1) (n - k + 1)$ can be re-expressed as

$$\sum_{k = 0}^n (k + 1) (n + 2) - 
\sum_{k = 0}^n [(k + 1) (k + 1)]. \tag{1}$$

The first summation from expression (1) above is
$$ (n+2) \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k = (n+2) \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) (n+1)(n+2). \tag{2}$$

The second summation from expression (1) above is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^2 = \left(\frac{1}{6}\right) (n+2)(2n+3)(n+1). \tag{3}$$

Taking common factors between expressions (2) and (3) above, you have that the overall computation is
$$\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)(n+1)(n+2) ~~[3(n+2) - (2n + 3)] $$

$$= ~~ \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) = \binom{n+3}{3}.$$

Comment: The OP specifically requires that generating functions be used, but nice answer very creative I like that,!

Comment: @ATB I would not have posted such an answer if the OP's question (re generating functions) had not already been resolved.  My understanding of the mathSE protocol is that once that happens, it becomes *open season* for alternative approaches.