# Prove by induction $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}( k+1)( n-k+1) =\binom{n+3}3$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction

Prove by induction :

$$\displaystyle \sum _{k=0}^{n}( k+1)( n-k+1) =\binom{n+3}{3}$$

induction basis: $n=0$

$$\displaystyle \sum _{k=0}^{n}( 0+1)( 0-0+1) =1=\binom{3}{3}$$

For $n+1$:

\begin{aligned}
\sum _{k=0}^{n+1}( n+1+1)( n+1-(n+1)+1) & =\sum _{k=0}^{n}( k+1)( n-k+1) +( n+2)(( n+1) -( n+1) +1)\\
 & =\binom{n+3}{3} +( n+2)\\
\end{aligned}

I had to stop here because I realize there is a mistake ...

Unfortunately, I didn't succeed in many ways.

Comment: I know you asked for an induction proof so this doesn't answer that aspect, but a *combinatorial* proof is readily available for this.  On the RHS this counts the number of subsets of size $3$ of the set $\{-1,0,1,2,\dots,n,n+1\}$ while the LHS counts the same but by breaking apart based on the value of the middle element, calling it $k$, noting that if the middle value was $k$ there are $k+1$ choices smaller than $k$ remaining in $\{-1,0,1,\dots,n,n+1\}$ for the smallest number in the subset and there are $(n-k+1)$ choices larger.

Comment: Hint: $(n+2)^2= (k+1 + n-k+1)^2 = (k+1)^2 + 2 (k+1)(n-k+1) + (n-k+1)^2$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yep: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4124710/683666

Comment: This reminded me of a question I have asked some time before: [How to show that $\sum_{k=1}^n k(n+1-k)=\binom{n+2}3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1113556). You can see various related posts [among the linked questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1113556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set up the induction correctly by getting the base case and stating your induction hypothesis.

For the induction step:

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}(k+1)((n\color{red}{+1})-k+1)$  You seem to have forgotten this red $\color{red}{+1}$.

So, we have $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}(k+1)((n\color{red}{+1})-k+1) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n(k+1)(n-k+1)\color{red}{+\sum\limits_{k=0}^n(k+1)}+(n+2)$.

This should hopefully get you back on track.

> The first summation simplifies to $\binom{n+3}{3}$ per induction hypothesis, the second summation simplifies to $\binom{n+2}{2}$ recognizing it as the $n+1$'st triangular number.  So we have $\binom{n+3}{3}+\binom{n+2}{2}+\binom{n+2}{1}=\binom{n+3}{3}+\binom{n+3}{2}=\binom{n+4}{3}=\binom{(n+1)+3}{3}$ using Paschal's identity to finish.

Comment: Thank you, I succeeded with the induction, but I didn't get why we are adding the sigma of k+1, where the sigma k+1 came from?
just if you can explain the sigma after the original sigma in the line I will appreciate that.

Comment: @ATB Do you see where the red $+1$ came from in the initial set up?  Do you see why $\sum a(b+1)=\sum ab + \sum a$?  Now, take as analogy rather than $a$ have $(k+1)$ and instead of $b$ we had $(n-k+1)$ and $b+1$ as $((n+1)-k+1)$.

Comment: Thanks, Understood, and where the last element $(n+2)$ came from?

Comment: @atb from breaking off the last term in the summation to be handled separately